# Why does my player object not set its rotation according to the ground object correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I'm making a 3D game in unity using c#, in which the player is on a kind of skateboard game object.

To make going up slopes seem more natural I've added this script to try and align the players rotation with the current ground object it's standing on:

variables:

```
public float rotationSpeed = 5f;

private Quaternion targetRotation;
```

Running in FixedUpdate:

```
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(rb.position, Vector3.down, out hit, Mathf.Infinity,   LayerMask.GetMask("Ground"))) {
            Vector3 groundNormal = hit.normal;
            Vector3 playerUp = transform.up;
            targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(playerUp, groundNormal) * rb.rotation;
        }

        rb.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(rb.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
```

My problem is that when the player jumps in the air and spins on the y axis, it will upon landing instead of setting its rotation to the ground object, be a little off. If I then run a line of code to set the rotational value to for example `(0, 0, 0)`, it will rotate back to those "off" coordinates.

Also the rigidbodys x and z values are freezed.

Examples of what happens:
[meow mewo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mzhj.png)
The player is cruisin' in a straight line on the ground, the rotational value on the x and z is 0 now

[the cat is grinding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT1Fe.png)
As the player moves up the sloped surface, its x and z rotations are changed accordingly

[kickflippin'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC2he.png)
The player object goes flying while spinning in the y axis, resulting in some changes on the x and y axis

[*bonk*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc9vJ.png)
Upon hitting the ground, the player object is not quite rotated as the ground (0 on x and z), but it has a little bit of an annoying offset on the x and z that it refuses to seek away from.

-I've tried changing the rotation to be rigidbody rotation instead of transform
-I've tried using a max slope angle
-I've tried drowning my sorrow in alcohol

How to fix this issue?

Comment: The floor is rotated.  The mouse rotation is with respect to the view, not the floor.

Comment: (Again sorry for bad english)
Sorry i don't quite understand, the transform rotation of my floor is 0 in all axis and of the slope its only rotated on the x axis to, you know, make it a slope. 
Furthermore i don't know what you mean by mouse rotation, nothing in the script is rotated using the computer mouse. 
If you could please elaborate just a bit further on this comment to make my newbie brain follow along, i would be EVER so delighted. :)

Comment: The lines on the floor run diagonal.  Mouse orientation is vertical/horizontal.  You want mouse to face diagonal to match lines on the floor.